# Encode table data to specific json format

Tags: php, android, html

Hi iam currently working on json based project.But iam having problem in encoding my data from my table like the below format.....I have seen a lot of json formats.....If any one can help me providing
php code snippet to encode exactly to such format.....

I need exactly such output where "data"  is the array name

```
    {
  "data":[
    {
      "Id":1,
      "Name":"Haben",
      "Surname":"Dave",
      "Age":22
    },
    {
      "Id":12,
      "Name":"Tomas",
      "Surname":"Haleka",
      "Age":32
    },
    {
      "Id":123,
      "Name":"Henok",
      "Surname":"Dave",
      "Age":28
    },
    {
      "Id":1,
      "Name":"Nafta",
      "Surname":"Dave",
      "Age":22
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I suggest you `print_r(json_decode($json, true))` (where `$json` is the JSON string in your question) and that will show you the structure of the PHP array that is required to get that output from `json_encode`. From that structure you should be able to work out how to generate it with database queries and fetches, try writing some code and then ask for help if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This will iterate through all selected rows and will encode them as `Array`. If you want to receive column names as they're in the table use below code.

```
$sql_query = "........";
$result = $db_connection->query($sql_query);
$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $rows[] = $r;
}
print json_encode(array('data'=> $rows));
```

If you don't want to receive same column names as in database you can change how you want to receive them. You'll have to edit your `while` loop to do so.

```
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $id = $r['user_id'];
    $name = $r['user_name'];
    $age  = $r['user_age'];
    $surname = $r['user_surname'];

    $rows[] = array('Id' => $id, 'Name' => $name, 'Age' => $age, 'Surname' => $surname);
}
```